# Implement Domain Services as Extension Methods for the repository

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

My understanding of Domain Services is that they perform tasks that are outside the boundaries of the related repository (CRUD related tasks).

Since .Net allows for Extension Methods, why not implement Domain Services as Extension Methods for Repositories and thus reduce the need to instantiate both a repository and a service when required?

I'd appreciate any comments.

Comment: I've thought about it for a while :-)

Comment: It seems an overkill to define service classes but I acknowledge the desire. I think implementing services using Extension Methods take you where DDD recommends but leaves the formality behind.

Answer (score 4):

> "My understanding of Domain Services is that they perform tasks that are outside the boundaries of the related repository (CRUD related tasks)."

Your understanding is different to mine, which is:

> Domain Services are used to encapsulate *domain* logic that falls outside the boundary of a single aggregate/entity/value object.

Repositories are concerned with *storage*, not domain logic, and therefore the two are VERY different things.

To be honest, the more I see questions on here surrounding **domain** services, the more I feel there is general confusion surrounding what **domain** services actually are. I think this may due to the ambiguity between:

1. Application Services - *(what the UI calls & where transactions begin)*
2. Infrastructure Services - *(things like an IEmailSenderService, ICreditCardPaymentGateway)*
3. Domain Services - *(provides pure domain logic, just like an aggregate/entity)*

Jimmy Bogard has written a [good article](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/) about their distinctive roles.

So to answer your question: It's a bad idea because you'd be mixing up two very distinct concepts and would be violating the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

Answer (score 0):

first issue is that your object will be full of infrastructure methods.

and second you must add another layer for these static classes containing extension methods, that will scatter the code of your service layer and domain model IMHO.

third is that you  must classify your objects by e.g. marker interface to filter the methods that they are able to call.

another issue is the context of execution, when you call a crud method on an object , it's would be executed client side or server side?

in addition is violating the persistence ignorant domain model,

and last is that in ORM's it's not a single object that will be saved but a session will be saved , recall [Unit of Work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html) pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A domain service may very well use multiple repositories. e.g. Customer and Order repositories at the same time.

So I think it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Services, as specified in DDD, are stateless methods (or, in the OO world, a class of related methods) so ultimately, extension methods do fit the bill.

The end result of using extension methods on your Repositories will be to expose the service interface from the Repository, while defining the implementation outside of the repository (which nicely reduces the efferent coupling of your repository). A similar result can be achieved in a more "OO-Friendly" manner by defining the service methods using delegate model (in .Net 3.5 and above you can leverage `Func<>` and `Action<>`), where the delegate implementations are defined elsewhere (and can be accessed via a [delegate based factory](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2011/01/21/software-factories-2.aspx)).

```
public class MyRepository
{
    //Repository Specific Methods
    public DomainObject FindById(...)
    ...

    //"Service" Methods as Delegates
    public Func<DomainObject, SomeResult> ProcessDomainObjectAndGetBackSomeResult
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceMethodFactory.ProcessDomainObjectAndGetBackSomeResult;
        }
    }
}
```