# CQRS & DDD - Domain Model Business Rules validation using cqrs read model

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm novice in DDD and CQRS patters and I want to have your opinion how a domain entity can be validated.
I'm going to use the common example Order->OrderLine, where Order is the AR.

The validation of business rules in an Aggregate is through the AR for consistency matters.
How can I validate a business rule that need data outside the Aggregate of Order?

I'm using also CQRS approach and I think that using the ReadModel to get the data that I need to make the validation of my business rules is not a bad option...What do you think?

Comment: Validation usually implies input, so it would happen on the command side (write side).  What validation would you be doing on the read model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With my experience of CQRS I associate the ReadModel as being eventually consistent, and therefore I wouldn't be 100% confident in the ReadModel representing the current state of the system. This becomes more the case when you want to distribute and replicate your ReadModels.

I would only want to use the ReadModel to limit the number of invalid commands being sent to your application.

It sounds to me that you want to start thinking about Domain Services, which can be used to encapsulate domain logic that falls outside the boundary of a single aggregate/entity/value object.

As David points out here [Implement Domain Services as Extension Methods for the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574125/implement-domain-services-as-extension-methods-for-the-repository/10649540#10649540), Jimmy Bogard has a definition http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/21/services-in-domain-driven-design/

Comment: Indeed Domain Services seem appropriate here; the question is: what other data is needed? I assume it's data that's stored in another aggregate?

Comment: Yes, data stored in another aggregate and for example that does not have any association with the AR. Domain Services seems a nice approach

Comment: Need for domain service is quite strong sign that there's lack of aggregate root.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, use the read model for command validation. I call this "command context" - the current state of the world, based on which command may be valid or invalid. In CQRS, this current state of the world is represented in your read model. User is making decisions based on it, what commands should be issued.

You may also consider various ways to guide user decisions, so that he doesn't issue invalid commands (warn in advance if username in not unique, etc).

Comment: As mouters points out the read model is eventually consistent.  Meaning it is the state of the world at some point in the past.  The domain is the only true "current state of the world".

Comment: If you try to support cross-AR consistency, then you are kind of giving up on scalability - which means, one less reason to be using cqrs in the first place.

Comment: Yep if the implementation is pure CQRS and uses two differente databases one for write and another for read that is updated through domain events, the Read Model is not a good approach for query consistent/up to dated data

Comment: What @driushkin says is completely correct; you can use the read model for **command validation** *(i.e. reducing the likelihood of the command failing)*, but I don't that was the question. The question appears to be about domain business rule invariants. The data involved here needs to be the 'source of truth'. I think the confusion comes from the authors use of the word 'validation'.